# 'texelFetch' : no matching overloaded function found in opengl es 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am using **OpenGL es 3.0** and my GLSL version **#version 300 es**.

I am trying to calculate luminous histogram in GPU.
i had identified that my device supports Vertex texture fetch and trying to read color information in vertex shader using texelFetch function.i am using texelFetch because i pass in every texture coordinate so as to read color information at every pixel.

Attaching the code

```
#version 300 es 
uniform sampler2D imageTexture;
in vec2 texturePosition;
const float SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024.0;
in vec4 position;
vec2 texturePos;
out vec3 colorFactor;
const vec3 W = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114); 
void main() {
    texturePos = texturePosition / SCREEN_WIDTH;
    vec3 color = texelFetch(imageTexture, texturePos.xy,0).rgb;
    float luminance = dot(color.xyz,W);
    colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (luminance *  0.00784313725), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
};
```

now getting the error 'texelFetch' : no matching overloaded function found.

Could somebody help with error and provide suggestion to calculate luminous histogram in GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

texturePos needs to be an ivec2, with integer texture coordinates (i.e. the pixel position in the texture) rather than normalized [0.0 1.0] floating point coordinates.

The code below should work:

```
#version 300 es 
uniform sampler2D imageTexture;
in ivec2 texturePosition;
in vec4 position;
out vec3 colorFactor;
const vec3 W = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114); 
void main() {
    vec3 color = texelFetch(imageTexture, texturePosition, 0).rgb;
    float luminance = dot(color, W);
    colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (luminance *  0.00784313725), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
};
```

But you need to feed the 'texturePosition' input array with integers containing all the (x,y) pixel coordinates you want to include in your histogram as integers. (with VBOs).

As pointed out in the comments, you'll need to use glVertexAttribIPointer() to feed integer types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Could you provide any samples that does a full texture reads in vertex  shader (getting the color value in vertex shader)

Comment: now the code is compiling but still not working as excepted                                                                                                                                                                      `GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(Handle, 2, **GLES30.GL_INT_VEC2**, false,0,  mtextureCoordinates);       `                                                                          is this the right way to pass the coordinates?

Comment: I'd use `GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(Handle, 2, GLES30.GL_INT, false,0, mtextureCoordinates);`  And of course that array needs to be prefilled by you manually as an init step.

Comment: As a side note, you might need to add 0.5 to both the x and y coordinates of gl_Position so that the GL_POINT you draw is right in the center of the pixel and not between two pixels.

Comment: thanks ,will try that :),in between can i do a full texture read using normalized coordinate using texture function in vertex shader

Comment: AFAIK, yes. You can just use texture2D(...) instead of texelFetch(). Might not be easier for an histogram though since you probably want to sample each pixel exactly and not have filtering or things like that.

Comment: @vishnudinakaran If you want to pass integer attributes to your shader, and use them as integer types in the shader, you need to use `glVertexAttribIPointer()`. Note the additional `I` in the function name.

Comment: Good call. I didn't even know about that myself.